# How to know whether I reached a correct Canonical Cover?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-schema, functional-dependencies

I know how to get the canonical cover throgh some steps.

But, how can I make sure that this is the minimal and correct canonical cover?

Here is an Example with my try:

```
R = {A, B, C, D, E}
F = {A->BC, CD->E, B->D, E->A}
```

Here is what I have done:

Only one step and I am done:

`C` is extraneous in `CD->E`

My `Fc = {A->BC, D->E, B->D, E->A}`

But I could not go further than that. Also I could not trust the result!!

Edit: I also has another solution, which is: `{A->BCE, B->D}`

Edit: I also has another solution, which is: `{A->BCED}`

Which one is the correct?

Comment: How is `{A->BCED}` a solution? How do you get `E->A` from that?

Comment: @ypercube Good point, The need of `E->A` is to get to `A`. So, I do not need it in my `FDs` because I already now `A`. Am I correct in my reasoning, or does this reasoning means I do not understood canonical cover function?

Comment: What do you mean with "I now `A`"? Is A any special than the other attributes?

Comment: @ypercube I mean A is already  there in `{A->BCED}`

Comment: First, you need to read more about the "extraneous" concept. *"`C` is extraneous in `CD->E`"* does not seem right.

Comment: @ypercube That why I came here, to seek knowledge from this community. Could  you clarify it for me.

Comment: @ypercube I ended up with a conclusion that is already a canonical cover